# Bundling a Kivy/Python App into an easily installable .app file for mac

Tags: python, macos, kivy, pyinstaller

I have been writing a graphical data management app in Python/Kivy for MacOS, and when I am done, I would like the end user to be able to install it without touching the command line. The computers that it is intended for already have python, but not Kivy. I was wondering what the easiest approach would be, perhaps an installer that would just execute 'pip install kivy' in the command line, or a python file using the OS module that installs it, or maybe pyinstaller. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually mentioned in the Kivy documentation [here](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-osx.html). Read more for customizing your install.

### Prerequisites

For a basic install, you first need to install PyInstaller and Cython. Do this with `pip3 install PyInstaller, Cython`.

### Bugs

There is a bug in setuptools that causes PyInstaller to not work. You need to have a version of setuptools less than 45.0.0 to work. To do this, run the following command `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools==44.1.1`. Finally, you are ready to package

### Creating *.spec file

PyInstaller works off of a *.spec file. To create this, as said by the Kivy documentation, run the following command:

```sh
pyinstaller -y --clean --windowed --name <the name of the *.app> \
  --exclude-module _tkinter \
  --exclude-module Tkinter \
  --exclude-module enchant \
  --exclude-module twisted \
  /path/to/main/program.py
```

Remember to replace `<the name of the *.app>` with what you want the name of the *.app to be, and `/path/to/main/program.py` with the path to your main python program file. The path can be relative too. This will take a bit, but will produce a file with an extension of a *.spec, which you will use to customize the app, create a directory called `build`, which you can delete, and create a directory called `dist`. Inside the `dist` directory, you will find your application.

## Debugging

If when you open your app it immediately closes, you have an error. To find out what it is, find the app in Finder, right-click it, and select "Show Package Contents```. Go inside a folder called "Contents", then inside a folder called "MacOS", in which you will see a lot of files. Find a file with a little "exec" icon on it with the name of the *.app file. Double-click this. This will bring up a terminal window with errors and console output. Copy-paste the error into Google, which should help, and also feel free to comment it here, and I will try to check it out!